# Vimeo API upload video with PHP not working

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere, please redirect me to the answer and I will delete this question (BTW I have searched on here but not found it).

I'm setting up the Vimeo API so I can upload to my vimeo account through a web interface. I have followed the tutorials on how to use video upload on Vimeo dev site but they are not working.

This is the code I have (taken from vimeo tutorials):

```
require 'sdk/autoload.php';
use Vimeo\Vimeo;
$client = new Vimeo("{client_id}", "{client_secret}", "{access_token}");

$file_name = "test-video.MOV";
$uri = $client->upload($file_name, array(
  "name" => "Untitled",
  "description" => "The description goes here."
));

$response = $client->request($uri . '?fields=transcode.status');
if ($response['body']['transcode']['status'] === 'complete') {
  print 'Your video finished transcoding.';
} elseif ($response['body']['transcode']['status'] === 'in_progress') {
  print 'Your video is still transcoding.';
} else {
  print 'Your video encountered an error during transcoding.';
}

$response = $client->request($uri . '?fields=link');
echo "Your video link is: " . $response['body']['link'];
```

The response I get from this is a HTTP ERROR 500. However, the video does appear to be loaded into Vimeo with the correct title and description, but it is empty of any content i.e. the video file itself does not appear to be uploaded.

For reference, I have the correct access keys with the correct permissions set and uploading is enabled in the vimeo dev account.

UPDATE: I've turned on error display and this is the error which is displayed.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'TusPhp\Tus\Client' not found in /home/hp3-linc1-nfs2-z/400/506400/user/htdocs/vimeo-upload/sdk/src/Vimeo/Upload/TusClient.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /home/hp3-linc1-nfs2-z/400/506400/user/htdocs/vimeo-upload/sdk/autoload.php(27): require() #1 [internal function]: {closure}('Vimeo\\Upload\\Tu...') #2 /home/hp3-linc1-nfs2-z/400/506400/user/htdocs/vimeo-upload/sdk/src/Vimeo/Vimeo.php(592): spl_autoload_call('Vimeo\\Upload\\Tu...') #3 /home/hp3-linc1-nfs2-z/400/506400/user/htdocs/vimeo-upload/sdk/src/Vimeo/Vimeo.php(338): Vimeo\Vimeo->perform_upload_tus('test-video.MOV', 15473903, Array) #4 /home/hp3-linc1-nfs2-z/400/506400/user/htdocs/vimeo-upload/index.php(20): Vimeo\Vimeo->upload('test-video.MOV', Array) #5 {main} thrown in /home/hp3-linc1-nfs2-z/400/506400/user/htdocs/vimeo-upload/sdk/src/Vimeo/Upload/TusClient.php on line 8
```

The code in TusClient.php looks like this:

```
namespace Vimeo\Upload;

class TusClient extends \TusPhp\Tus\Client
{
    /**
     * Sets the url for retrieving the TUS upload.
     * @param string $url
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setUrl(string $url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"The response I get from this"_ - from what exactly? Your script? Upload? First request? Second request?

Comment: From running the script

Comment: Well, if that's the case, PHP's error log should have information about the actual error.

Comment: Looks like it was a dependencies issue. I reinstalled the SDK with composer and it seems to have fixed it.